# Volume of a body bounded by planes

Tags: calculus, analysis

I'm just after the lecture about Fubini's theorem. And I "don't feel" how to do some exercises. Here is an example:

What is the volume of the body bounded by: the graph of the function $f(x,y)=1+2x+3y$, rectangle $R=[1,2]\times[0,1]$, four vertical planes determined by $R$ and the plane $xy$.

How should I write the integrals? How do the boundaries determine limits of the integral?

Comment: By "the plane $xy$" do you mean the plane determined by the $x$ and $y$ axes, i.e. the plane $z=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that by "the plane $xy$" you mean the plane determined by the $x$ and $y$ axes, i.e. the plane $z=0$.

In that case, I believe the volume would be
$$\int_1^2{\int_0^1{(1+2x+3y)}\;dy}\;dx$$

This works since the function is positive in the desired rectangle $R$.

How the boundaries determine the integral limits should be obvious from the answer.

Comment: What would we have to do if a function wasn't positive in the given set?

Comment: @Novsar: Then you would integrate the absolute value, $|1+2x+3y|$. If the "signed volume" was desired (similar to signed area in 2 dimensions) you would leave it without the absolute value.